Orbeon Forms Configuration Issue: "Data source SQL not configured" Error
I'm trying to configure Orbeon Forms to use SQL Server instead of SQLite, but I keep encountering this error:
2024-07-01T18:53:45,482 ERROR relational - Data source `sqlite` not configured
2024-07-01T18:53:45,484 ERROR XFormsServer - The following Orbeon Forms configurations are incomplete:
The database configuration is missing or incomplete.

Configuration Details
orbeon.xml:
<Resource
    name="jdbc/sqlserver"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    initialSize="3"
    maxActive="10"
    maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="30000"
    poolPreparedStatements="true"
    validationQuery="select 1"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    username="orbeon_user"
    password="my-password"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=OrbeonDB;trustServerCertificate=true"/>

web.xml:
<resource-ref>
    <description>DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/sqlserver</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

properties-local.xml:
<properties>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider" value="sqlserver"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.sqlserver.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.sqlserver.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.235;databaseName=OrbeonDB"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.sqlserver.user" value="orbeon_user"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.sqlserver.password" value="my-password"/>
</properties>

orbeon.properties:
oxf.xforms.log.level=info
oxf.fr.persistence.provider=sqlserver

I've placed the JDBC driver (mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar) in both the Tomcat lib directory and the Orbeon WEB-INF/lib.
Issue with Tomcat Startup
After these changes, Tomcat fails to start with the following error:
01-Jul-2024 23:24:04.429 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess Error reloading memory user database [UserDatabase] from updated source [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/conf/tomcat-users.xml]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

What I Tried:

Verified all configurations.
Placed the JDBC driver in the Tomcat lib directory.
Restarted Tomcat multiple times.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You can remove orbeon.properties. No such configuration file exists. And in your properties-local.xml, add the property below to disable SQLite.
<property
    as="xs:boolean"
    name="oxf.fr.persistence.sqlite.active"
    value="false"/>


Hello! I did that, thank you. Now I try to understand what I modified wrong in the configuration files, because when I try to enter the orbeon link I get error 404...

It was a port conflict! I solved it!

@GeorgianaIuliana Excellent, I am glad you got Orbeon Forms up and running.
